# Writing dataset to xml with nested tables

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable, dataset, relation

There exists a dataset class called dsetDataManager in my code.
There will be two tables I am referencing in this question: DataConfigDataTable, SpecEquationDataTable.

DataConfig is the parent table and SpecEquation is the child table.

Here is my existing code:

```
    Dim dset As New dsetDataManager
    Dim dataconfig As New dsetDataManager.DataConfigDataTable
    dataconfig.AddDataConfigRow(name,
                      name,
                      precision,
                      "smartmethodname",
                      "stringevalstring",
                      True,
                      "passingstring",
                      "passingstringinclusion",
                      "0",
                      "datacolumntype",
                      True,
                      True,
                      "networkanalyzertraces",
                      "spectrumanalyzertraces",
                      "noisefiguretraces",
                      0.5,
                      "parser")
  dset.Tables.Add(dataconfig)

  Dim specequation As New dsetDataManager.SpecEquationDataTable
  specequation.AddSpecEquationRow(dataconfig.Rows(0),
                                      j + 1,
                                      k + 1,
                                      arr_minEquation(equationCounter),
                                      arr_maxEquation(equationCounter),
                                      "Inclusive",
                                      "Inclusive")
   dset.WriteXML("example\path\test.xml")
```

These methods and tables are all custom so please just ASSUME this code works and are created correctly. As they most certainly are. My issue:

When I write the XML I am provided two sperate tables, a dataconfig table with a start tag, then the rows, then an end tag. Then there is the specequation table with a start tag, the rows, and then an end tag.

What I really want is a nested table in the xml. I want the specequation table to be inside of the ending tag of the dataconfig table. Any tips on how I can do this? I thought the .merge() method would work but I am getting an 'object reference is not set to instance of an object' exception.

EXISTING XML:

[image]

WHAT I WANT: 
[image]

Again to reiterate, the parent/child relationship already exists between these tables. The purpose of my program is to auto-generate useful xml files containing data representing these tables. It is abosolutely crucial that this nesting happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a relationship between the two tables, using a DataRelation.
This requires adding a field to link the two

You can then set the DataRelation to Nested = True.  For example

```
Dim rel As DataRelation = dSet.Relations.Add("relHeader", dSet.Tables("DataConfig").Columns("Link"), dSet.Tables("SpecEquation").Columns("Link"))
rel.Nested = True
```

Finally hide the columns :

```
datatable.Columns("Link").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
```